# Swiftで繰り返し２乗法の勉強している際に「Swift runtime failure: arithmetic overflow」というエラーで詰まってしまいました

Tags: swift

pythonで書かれたコードを参考にし、下記のようなコードを書いたのですが n >= 33 から　
「Thread 1: Swift runtime failure: arithmetic overflow」
というエラーが出て動かなくなってしまいます。
Swiftでこのような大きな数字の扱い方を教えていただけないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

```
let n = 33
var x = 3

func powByMyself(n: Int, x: Int) -> Int {
    var x = x
    var n = n
    var ans = 1
    var count = 0
    while n > 0 {
        count += 1
        if n & 1 == 1 {
            ans *= x
            print(ans)
        }
        x *= x
        n >>= 1
    }
    return ans
}

powByMyself(n: n, x: x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Swiftでこのような大きな数字の扱い方を教えていただけないでしょうか。

Swiftの標準ライブラリには、Pythonのように「メモリの許す限りで任意の精度の整数を扱う」機能は含まれていません。なんらかの別ライブラリを探して利用するようにする必要があります。

例えば、`swift biginteger`で検索して出てきたSwift Package Manager用の[NumberKitというパッケージ](https://github.com/objecthub/swift-numberkit)を使うと、以下のように書けます。

```
import Foundation
import NumberKit

let n: BigInt = 33
var x: BigInt = 3

func powByMyself(n: BigInt, x: BigInt) -> BigInt {
    var x = x
    var n = n
    var ans: BigInt = 1
    var count = 0
    while n > 0 {
        count += 1
        if n & 1 == 1 {
            ans *= x
            print(ans)
        }
        x *= x
        n >>= 1
    }
    return ans
}

powByMyself(n: n, x: x) //->3 5559060566555523
```

型が`Int`となってしまうところの一部分を`NumberKit.BigInt`に置き換えるだけで、通常の演算子等がそのまま使えるようになっています。探せばSwift用の巨大整数演算ライブラリは他にも見つかると思いますが、ほぼ同様に使えるようになっているだろうと思います。

Comment: paizaなどの競技プログラミングのできる、サイトで回答と同じようなコードを書いても動かない理由が理解できて嬉しいです！

Comment: ライブラリが読み込めない環境でSwift言語を使ってこのような問題は解くことは、できない、もしくは非常に難しいということでしょうか？

Comment: @daiishi さん、コメントありがとうございます。「非常に難しい」の方になりますね。`BigInt`のソースはざっくり千数百行、あなたの`powByMyself`を実行するのに最低限の機能にすればそれよりははるかに短くはなりますが、かなりのプログラミング能力が要求されるのは間違いありません。